# Package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have Cloud functions project and i moved the project from my old laptop to my new laptop.

I have installed everything that necessary. My problem is when i try `firebase deploy` it gives me that error:

> !  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions.
> Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.

I did that i have been told, but still it gives me the same error.
What should i do? And how i direct the npm install to my functions directory?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have followed the instructions to install firebase-functions@latest IN the functions folder as well as installed latest firebase-tools in top-level folder. I still get same error. Anyone? I've tried all 3 solutions posed here.

Answer (score 8):

You need to run `sudo npm install --save firebase-functions@latest` in your `functions` directory. Cannot be in any other directory.

In Flutter this will be in

```
/path_to_your_flutter_project/functions
```

Hope this helped someone

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
You just need to run `npm install -g firebase-tools`

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
/usr/local/bin/firebase -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js
+ firebase-tools@7.0.0
```

That fixed my problem.

Comment: After installation `firebase-tools` globally still have the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Update `firebase-admin` and make sure your root `package.json` file points to your `functions` folder